# Fatal error: Array index out of range, map app

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I'm a rookie and could really use your help. I'm trying to make a map app in xcode, swift, but with a table before. When I start my app in the simulator, the table view is cool. When I click on a field (it should take me to a new viewcontroller with a map) it crashes and says [fatal error: Array index out of range] highlighting this code

```
let sportskiObjekat = sportskiObjektiArray[izabranObjekat]
```

The whole code in this table view controller goes like this:

```
import UIKit

class SportskiObjektiTableViewController: UITableViewController {

   var sportskiObjektiArray = Array<SportskiObjekti>()
   var izabranObjekat:Int = -1


   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
       // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

       // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
       // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =   self.editButtonItem()
       let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SportskiObjekti", ofType: "plist")!
       let array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as! Array<Dictionary<String,AnyObject>>

       for dict in array {
           let sportskiObjekti = SportskiObjekti(dict: dict)
           sportskiObjektiArray.append(sportskiObjekti)
       }

   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

  // MARK: - Table view data source

   override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
   }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return self.sportskiObjektiArray.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        let objekat = self.sportskiObjektiArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = objekat.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text=objekat.location

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

    {
        //naknadno//
        izabranObjekat = indexPath.row
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mapViewControllerSegueIdentifier", sender: self)
    }

//novo
   // MARK: - Navigation

     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
         let sportskiObjekat = sportskiObjektiArray[izabranObjekat]
         let mapVC = segue.destinationViewController as! MapViewController
         mapVC.objekat = sportskiObjekat

    }
 }
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's a good idea to check if the segue identifier is the right one, I'm not sure if this is going to work but try putting an if segue.identifier == "mapViewControllerSegueIdentifier" in the prepareForSegue function

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to reload the UI in order to populate the cells with data. so after you append your array, add the reloadData()

```
   self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Your problem was in here, your `indexPath.row`

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!{  //<-- indexpath
     let sportskiObjekat = sportskiObjektiArray[indexPath.row]
     let mapVC = segue.destinationViewController as! MapViewController
     mapVC.objekat = sportskiObjekat
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, forgot to tell that im filling up the table from a property list array, dont know if it is important for this? I tried the reloadData, but that didnt change anything

Comment: can you check if you are getting data into your array

Comment: Yes I am. The data is getting into array and it is filling up the table, the problem starts when i click on one of the objects in the table. It should send  me to my mapViewController, instead it crashes, and says the Array index out of range thing.

Comment: check my edit the probelm was the way you got the indexpath in your prepareForSegue